# Javascript AJAX function not working properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a function that sends a GET request to a php script and checks if the script returned any output. It works great, but when I try to add another function that checks for something similar, both of them fail. What am I missing?

```
    function checkUsername(usr,n) {
        var user = usr.val(), xmlhttp;

        //var str = document.getElementById('email').value;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                if (xmlhttp.responseText != "") {
                    usr.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                    updateTips( n );
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxValidate.php?type=user&q="+user,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

The above works perfectly, when adding this function, none of them work:

```
    function checkEmail(em,n) {
        var email = em.val(), xmlhttp;

        //var str = document.getElementById('email').value;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            //document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                if (xmlhttp.responseText != "") {
                    em.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
                    updateTips( n );
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            }
          }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxValidate.php?type=email&q="+email,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: Why is it `.val()`? Is it a jQuery object? If not then it should be `.value`. Even if it is somewhat consistent with the top one, I just want clarification.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that, yes, it's a jQuery object.

Comment: you are using `.val()` and `.addClass()` in your code - those look a lot like jQuery functions - why don't you use jQuery ajax then?

Comment: +1 for the good question. Still very interested in finding out what's wrong with the above.

Comment: if you can see that you're reuing code, try and refactor (i.e. change) it so you do every task just once. here, make a function that returns a new XMLHttpRequest object

Comment: So you have this first function that does an AJAX request. Then you copy-pasted the code into another function and now it doesn't work. This is the reason why jQuery exists.

Comment: @Or W Also, note that you have implicit global variables in your code. You might want to get rid of those.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your supportive comments about the quality of my code, can you please ALSO answer my original question?

Comment: I think you're going to have to define "they fail", with supporting errors from your Javascript console.

Answer (score 0):

In both functions, let the first line be:

```
var xmlhttp;
```

Comment: That helps, though it's solving the problem. If I comment out the the call for the checkUsername() function, the checkEmail() function work. Otherwise, it's not working.

Comment: I've added the updated script you wrote above, and duplicated the checkEmail function, changed the name to checkUsername(usr,n), changed the rest of the parts that needs to change to be according to user instead of email and i'm getting the same response, there's some sort of a collision between the two.

Comment: @Or W Above you say that if you comment out the code inside the checkUsername() function, then checkEmail() does work, and otherwise not. Obviously, the collision happens between those two functions. I think you failed to declare the `xmlhttp` variable in those two functions. That would explain the collision.

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
   function createRequestObject() {
        var xmlhttp=null;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        return xmlhttp;
    }

function checkUsername(usr,n) {
    var user = usr.val();
    var xmlhttp = createRequestObject();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
         if (xmlhttp.responseText != "") {
            usr.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( n );
            return false;
         } else {
            return true;
         }
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxValidate.php?type=user&q="+user,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function checkEmail(em,n) {
    var email = em.val();
    var xmlhttp = createRequestObject();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
          if (xmlhttp.responseText != "") {
            em.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
            updateTips( n );
            return false;
          } else {
            return true;
          }
       }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxValidate.php?type=email&q="+email,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```